# Convert multipart body to java object

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, multipartform-data, multipart

I'm trying to use java + camel to read a multipart file and converting it to object to process it.
My multipart file is composed of 2 kind of datas: an application/json and an application/octet-stream
Is there a way to convert it to some kind of object that i can work with?
basically I'm sending a get REST request to an application that respondes with a multipart file. I can't figure it out how to convert the response body: the application/json to my POJO and the application/octet-stream to a DataHandler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle multipart in camel, you can use `unmarshal().mimeMultipart()`. After this line, Camel Exchange contains an `AttachmentMessage`, the body of it is the first part of the multipart. The next parts can be obtained by calling `attachmentMessage.getAttachmentObjects()` in Camel processor. For more information on how `unmarshal().mimeMultipart()` works, see the source code of method `unmarshall()` in `org.apache.camel.dataformat.mime.multipart.MimeMultipartDataFormat`.
Further actions depend on your case. For example, if the first part of a multipart always contains a json object of your `SimplePojo` class, then you can use `unmarshal().json(SimplePojo.class)` immediately after `unmarshal().mimeMultipart()`. Then Camel body will contain your pojo. DataHandlers for the next parts can be obtained as follows:

```
DataHandler dataHandler = attachmentObjects.get("test.txt").getDataHandler(); 
// test.txt comes from the filename field of the Content-Disposition header in case you have multipart/form-data.
```

Below is an example of processing a response from a REST service located at {{http.url}}, in a multipart format of the following form:

```
--Boundary_2411_1961957611_1491990591774
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="part1"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 

{
  "id": 123,
  "name": "simple pojo"
}
--Boundary_2411_1961957611_1491990591774
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="part2"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

test
--Boundary_2411_1961957611_1491990591774--
```

Camel RouteBuilder:

```
from("direct:start")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethods.GET))
    .to("{{http.url}}")
    .unmarshal().mimeMultipart()
    .unmarshal().json(SimplePojo.class)
    .process(exchange -> {

        AttachmentMessage attachmentMessage = exchange.getMessage(AttachmentMessage.class);
        SimplePojo simplePojo = attachmentMessage.getBody(SimplePojo.class);

        Map<String, Attachment> attachmentObjects = attachmentMessage.getAttachmentObjects();
        DataHandler dataHandler = attachmentObjects.get("test.txt").getDataHandler();

    })

.to("mock:end");
```

SimplePojo:

```
public class SimplePojo {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    //...
    //getters, setters
}
```

In order for `unmarshal().mimeMultipart()` and `unmarshal().json(SimplePojo.class)` to work, you must have dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-mail</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```