# Get key-value pairs from multipart/form-data HTTP POST request in Camel

Tags: java, http, apache-camel, multipartform-data

I have an endpoint setup using Apache Camel to receive a multipart/form-data HTTP request. Essentially I am trying to submit a data file and a configuration file for processing. The request is as follows (generated by Postman):

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8900
Content-Length: 363
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="data-file.json"
Content-Type: application/json

(data)
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="config"; filename="config-file.json"
Content-Type: application/json

(data)
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

My route is set up like so:

```
@Component
public class FileReceiverRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        rest()
                .post("/upload")
                .consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.off)
                .route().routeId("upload-route")
                .unmarshal().mimeMultipart()
                .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, () -> UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .to("file:{{temp.input.files.dir}}")
                .process(configFileProcessor)
                // on to further processing
    }
}
```

And my config file processor:

```
@Component
public class ConfigFileProcessor implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Message message = exchange.getIn();
        AttachmentMessage attachmentMessage = exchange.getMessage(AttachmentMessage.class);
        Map<String, Attachment> attachmentObjects = attachmentMessage.getAttachmentObjects();

        // this fails - the key is instead the file name "config-file.json"
        Attachment configAttachment = attachmentObjects.get("config");
    }
}
```

I want to be able to retrieve the key-value pairs from the form-data and process the data and config files accordingly. Instead I get the following behaviour:

- The first value in the form (in this case `data-file.json`) is parsed into the Camel message body, and the key seems to be discarded. The rest of the entries are parsed into an `AttachmentMessage`. This behaviour is documented here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67566273/11248602
- The keys in the `AttachmentMessage` are not the original keys from the form-data request, but the filenames (e.g. `config-file.json`)

Is there any way to parse this request into a map or similar structure so that all the original keys and values can be accessed?

Comment: What if you browse the attachmenttObjects map, examine ,for each entry, its headers (using Attachment#getHeaderNames()), hoping to find the 'Content-Disposition' one (which includes the real name) ?

Comment: @TacheDeChoco thanks yes that does work to get the key :) Feel free to create an answer with that and I will accept. Doesn't solve the first entry being parsed into the body of the message, but I can live with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of clarity, as the proposed solution here above seems to work, a bit more explanations (although it is more a workaround than a solution):

Starting from:

```
Map<String, Attachment> attachmentObjects = attachmentMessage.getAttachmentObjects();
```

It is possible to browse all map entries, and for each found `Attachment` object, examine the attachment headers using `getHeaderNames()`, among other the 'Content-Disposition' one:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="data-file.json"
```

which can finally be parsed to grab the form **name** ('data' in this example).

Not straightforward true, but this apparently works...